# Eclipse does not detect contents of public schema in jpa mode

Tags: eclipse, jpa, facet

After successfully reverse engineering  my db using hibernate tools i tried to do the same  using jpa facet mode. The connection is successfully made to the db ( same connetion used earlier for hibernate rev-eng)  and it detects the contents of all other schemas (pg_catalog, pg_information, pg_toast_temp) except the important one : "public" . Any ideas on how to get it to detect the public schema and generate entities from it? I would like to mention that my persistence.xml is pretty much empty:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="testjpa">
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Where in the UI does Eclipse detect "the contents of all other schemas"? Are you talking the Data Source Explorer? JPA Entity Generation? A drop-down list in the JPA Details view?

Comment: @BrianVosburgh see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027394/jdbc-connection-created-ineclipse-does-not-work-as-it-should please; this is now my problem. it seems that  data source explorer shows the same thing  regardless of the name of the database( non-existent or not) and the schemas in it.

Comment: ok solved the jdbc issue but now i still cannot see any tables (or schemas for that matter) when trying  to generate entities from tables

Comment: You might look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936741/db2-jpa-entities-from-table/16944737#16944737 - maybe we can determine where the problem is....