# JDBC connection created ineclipse does not work as it should

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I created a jdbc connection  which seems to show  all  the tables from all the other schemas ( information_schema, pg_catalog, pg_toast_temp_1 )  except for the tables in the public schema. Any solutions?

Previously it worked i dont know what i did wrong but now i don't see any of the tables i should .

Comment: I tried  to create another schema. That one won't even come up in the data source explorer view.

Comment: this is odd.. i specified a non-existent database name  and the ping still succeds and in the data source explorer view it apppears as if i am connected to this non-existent database . I thought that you need the name of a real datbase..

Comment: Without showing your code, exact error messages if any, Pg version, PgJDBC version, explaining your setup more, etc it's very hard to say what could be going on.

Comment: @CraigRinger problem solved below

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved: When you create a jdbc connection in eclipse you must specify, among other things
a) database name
b) connection url
c) username
d)password
I thought that if you specify the database name  there's no more need to specify it in the url. Turns out i was wrong. b) in my case must be jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb . And a) is just a SCREEN NAME. I didn;t know that and my url did not have the db name in it ( ie jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ ) . a) can have whatever value

Comment: Interesting. The database name, etc, should be sent to as a Properties dictionary to the JDBC driver during creation. Maybe Eclipse ignores it if you provide a URL? +1 for following up.